# How to enter recovery mode with an OTG keyboard?

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, external-keyboard

I would like to know how to boot my Mediatek tablet into recovery mode by using a physical keyboard (OTG) because my volume key doesn't work.
And I can't boot to the OS to enable the USB debugging.

Comment: Is your bootloader unlocked? Can you boot to bootloader mode?

Comment: I think that my bootloader is unlocked. How can I check that and boot to bootloader mode?

Comment: Make a search with your model number.

Comment: Does the unlocked boot.img mean that the bootloader is unlocked?

Comment: The boot.img from my firmware is unlocked.

Comment: Unlocked boot.img doesn't make sense. It's the bootloader which is locked or unlocked. You can get your stock recovery.img (or custom one like TWRP if bootloader is unlocked) and boot that from bootloader mode using `fastboot boot recovery.img`. But first you must be able to boot into bootloader mode. That has a different key combination than recovery mode. Key combinations are specific to devices and manufacturers.